# How to sort a CharmListView with a specific order?

Tags: gluon-mobile

Is it possible to sort a CharmListView in a specific order ?

The list contains the names of the BLE bluetooth devices in range. How to do a sort in the following way ? :

If the device contains a character string `:1-` then this device belongs to `Category XYZ`;
if the character string contains `:2-` then this device belongs to `Category XXX`. etc ...

When displaying the `CharmListView` we should see firstly `Category XYZ` , then `Category ABC`

In [CharmListView example](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.3.0/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/CharmListView.html#selectedItemProperty) The sorting is done with this code snippet :

```
    if(ascending){
        charmListView.setHeaderComparator((d1,d2) -> d1.compareTo(d2));
        charmListView.setComparator((s1,s2) -> Double.compare(s1.getDensity(), s2.getDensity()));
        ascending = false;
    } else {
        charmListView.setHeaderComparator((d1,d2) -> d2.compareTo(d1));
        charmListView.setComparator((s1,s2) -> Double.compare(s2.getDensity(), s1.getDensity()));
        ascending = true;
    }
```

I do not understand how `charmListView.setHeaderComparator((d1,d2) -> d2.compareTo(d1));` and
`CharmListView.setComparator((s1,s2) -> Double.compare(s2.getDensity(), s1.getDensity()));` are working.

By default, the headers are sorted in natural order (alphabetically). How to not sort alphabetically but just with a specific order that I provide ?

[image: Category XYZ should be on top]

`Category XYZ` should be on top

This is the source code of the class where the CharmListView is created.

```
package com.hacare.views;

import com.gluonhq.attach.ble.BleDevice;


import com.gluonhq.attach.ble.BleService;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CharmListCell;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CharmListView;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ListTile;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;

import com.hacare.objects.MyBleDevice;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;



public class PrimaryPresenter {

    /**
     * List of ble devices nearby
     */
    ObservableList<BleDevice> ble_device_list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private View primary;

    @FXML
    private CharmListView<BleDevice, String> ble_device_charmlistview;



    /**
     * Controller init function
     */
    public void initialize() {

        primary.showingProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                AppBar appBar = MobileApplication.getInstance().getAppBar();
                appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e ->
                        MobileApplication.getInstance().getDrawer().open()));
                appBar.setTitleText("Primary");
                appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.BLUETOOTH.button(e ->
                        buttonClick()));

            }
        });


        ble_device_charmlistview.setHeadersFunction(MyBleDevice::getO_device_type);
        ble_device_charmlistview.setComparator((o1, o2) -> {

            if(o2.getName().contains(":1-")){
                //test statement
                return 1;
            }
            //test statement
            return 0;
        });

        ble_device_charmlistview.setCellFactory(bleDeviceStringCharmListView -> new CharmListCell<BleDevice>(){
            @Override
            public void updateItem(BleDevice item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(item!=null && !empty){
                    ListTile tile = new ListTile();
                    tile.textProperty().add(item.getName());
                    Image image = new Image("/icon.png");
                    if(item.getName().contains("HAcare_Y4")){
                        image = new Image("imgs/y-type-y4_64x64.jpg");
                    }
                    else{
                        image = new Image("/icon.png");
                    }

                    tile.setPrimaryGraphic(new ImageView(image));
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(tile);
                }
            }
        });

        ble_device_charmlistview.selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, bleDevice, t1) ->
                {
                    System.out.println(ble_device_charmlistview.getSelectedItem().getAddress());
                }
        );

    }



    @FXML
    void buttonClick() {

        ble_device_list.clear();

        //dummy devices
        BleDevice device1 = new BleDevice();
        device1.setAddress("AB:CD:EF:GH:IJ:KL");
        device1.setName("HAcare_Y4:1-CW71");

        BleDevice device2 = new BleDevice();
        device2.setAddress("MN:CD:EZ:AH:FJ:CL");
        device2.setName("dummy device");


        BleDevice device3 = new BleDevice();
        device3.setAddress("AK:CD:ED:FE:AJ:KL");
        device3.setName("HAcare_Y4:1-AZ5K");



        ble_device_list.add(device1);
        ble_device_list.add(device2);
        ble_device_list.add(device3);
        ble_device_charmlistview.setItems(ble_device_list);

        BleService.create().ifPresent(ble ->
                ble.startScanningDevices().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends BleDevice> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    for (BleDevice device : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                        System.out.println("Device found: " + device.getName());
                        ble_device_list.add(device);
                        ble_device_charmlistview.setItems(ble_device_list);
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    }

}
```

Comment: Edit your question and post how you define the CharmListView? See updated [docs](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/6.0.6/com.gluonhq.charm.glisten/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/CharmListView.html). Do you use the `headerFunction`?

Comment: Yes I am using headerFunction. I also provided the source code

Comment: Do you use a `headerComparator`?

Comment: No, I do not understand how it works and how to use it on Strings

Comment: Just try it out, it is a regular comparator based on two strings. For instance, `(s1,s2) -> s2.compareTo(s1)` will reverse the natural order.

Comment: Well, thank you this is working, `category XYZ is on top`, but what happen if I had more than 2 categories. There is no specific way to set an order ?

Comment: You can always create your comparator (you are already doing it for each item), and apply any string comparison between s1 and s2.